# Save file in current directory/path for an ID

Tags: c#, file, directory, createfile

Help! I'm searching hours for an solution. I'm doing the same as the examples in the internet, but there is always an error. (I'm new in coding..)

My main aim is to save a opened file which is selected in a new folder for a new ID.Have any ideas ?

```
 var locationToCreateFolder = "C://";
        var folderName = textBox1.Text + textBox6.Text;
        var path = Path.Combine(locationToCreateFolder, folderName);

        OpenFileDialog fbd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fbd.Multiselect = true;


        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = fbd.FileName;

        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            File.Move(fbd.FileName, path);
            //new FileInfo(locationToCreateFolder).Directory.Create();
        }
```

Comment: whats the error

Comment: Code is not clear. You already saved the file name in the path variable. path = fbd.FileName; Then you are creating directory with the file name Directory.CreateDirectory(path); Is it your cause of issue or I am missing something.

Comment: The error is the chosen file cannot be created, because it already exists. But my aim is to chosen a file and then move it to a new folder for an Id.. not to create a new file